# Why isn't transform: translateY(-10rem) moving the child image element, that is within its parent element?

Tags: html, css, sass

The files are as such: `div.current-houses` > `figure.item.item--1` > `img.img.img--2`. So, I'm trying to position the image thats inside of its parent figure element so that it is centered. I used tranform: translateY(-10rem); to try and bring it up but that doesn't work. It just brings the whole img up and cuts itself as opposed to bringing up the lower section of the image that is out of bounds but not visible; it's as if it's never rendered the out of bounds image part

[image: view image]

```css
.current-houses {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: grey;
  
  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(11, 5vw);
}

.current-houses__item--2 {
  grid-row: 4 / 8;
  grid-column: 3 / -1;
/*The part in yellow is item    */
  background-color:yellow;
}

.current-houses__img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        display: block;
}

.current-houses__img--2 {
/* Just trying to move image down; however, it is not working.    */
  transform: translateY(1rem);
}

/* FIRST IMAGE JUST TO HELP WITH CONTEXT  */
.current-houses__item--1 {
            grid-row: 1 / 4;
            grid-column: 6 / 9;
}

.current-houses__img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="current-houses">
  
  <figure class="current-houses__item current-houses__item--1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512917774080-9991f1c4c750?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="" class="current-houses__img current-houses__img--1">
  </figure>
  
  <figure class="current-houses__item current-houses__item--2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475855581690-80accde3ae2b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="" class="current-houses__img current-houses__img--2">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a resource that someone could point me to also to learn how images work with HTML and CSS. I know maybe the generic stuff... but images just seem to have a mind of their own and always behave differently than I would expect

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet righ here in your question that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Your selector does not match the indicated HTML.

Comment: sorry just fixed that

Comment: @connexo I've added the code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your first problem is that you have width and height on the image in question set to 100%. What this does is crops that image to 100% of parent's height, and 100% of parent's width at the time of rendering. Therefore, when you try to move it you're moving an already set image (ie there is not tail bit to follow).

In the code snippet below, I changed height to auto, left width as 100%, and made sure overflow: hidden was set on item class. I also zoomed in your image and moved it around to demonstrate that your original problem is no longer present.

Cheers,

```css
.current-houses {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: grey;
  
  display: grid;
  
  gap: .5rem;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(11, 2rem);
}

.current-houses__item--2 {
  grid-row: 4 / -1;
  grid-column: 3 / -1;
/*The part in yellow is item    */
  background-color:yellow;
  
  /* Add in this line so excess image does not surpass boundaries */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.current-houses__img {
        width: 100%;
          /* Change Heighto to auto */
        height: auto;
        object-fit: cover;
        display: block;
}

.current-houses__img--2 {
/* Just trying to move image down; however, it is not working.    */
  transform: scale(1.5) translateY(1rem);
}

/* FIRST IMAGE JUST TO HELP WITH CONTEXT  */
.current-houses__item--1 {
            grid-row: 1 / 4;
            grid-column: 6 / 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="current-houses">
  
  <figure class="current-houses__item current-houses__item--1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512917774080-9991f1c4c750?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="" class="current-houses__img current-houses__img--1">
  </figure>
  
  <figure class="current-houses__item current-houses__item--2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475855581690-80accde3ae2b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="" class="current-houses__img current-houses__img--2">
  </figure>
</div>
```